# How to Update a Column in Microsoft Access with Multiplication Based on Boolean Values?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, datatable

I have a table named 'Uyeler' with the primary key 'TCKimlik.' The tables 'Borc', 'AidatDurum' and 'AylikAidat' have foreign keys based on this 'TCKimlik' value.

[image]

In the image above, I want to populate the 'ToplamBorc' column based on the boolean values being 'false' in the other tables below. The values in the columns with the same name in the respective tables should be multiplied, and the result should be placed in the 'ToplamBorc' column.

[image]
[image]

For example, if the 'Ocak' and 'Subat' columns are 'true' and the remaining columns are 'false,' it will write the value of 1000 (resulting from 500 * 2) to the 'ToplamBorc' colmn.

Comment: Should provide sample data as formatted text table, not images. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support and https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Where is Boolean data? Why does second table not have value in ID field? Why does it have a box with dash in each field? This does not appear to be a normalized data structure and what you want will not be simple. Expression in query will likely be too long and VBA will be needed or perhaps UNION query(s) to rearrange data to normalized structure. Saving calculated data is usually a bad idea. Calculate when needed.

Comment: Do these tables have 1-to-1 relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible all-SQL solution, using 5 fields - expand as needed. A UNION can have up to 50 SELECT lines.

Query: AA_UNION

```
SELECT UYEID, "Ocak" AS AA_Col, Ocak AS AA_Data FROM AylikAidat
UNION SELECT UYEID, "Subat", Subat FROM AylikAidat
UNION SELECT UYEID, "Mart", Mart FROM AylikAidat
UNION SELECT UYEID, "Nisan", Nisan FROM AylikAidat;
```

Query: AD_UNION

```
SELECT UYEID, "Ocak" AS AD_Col, Ocak *-1 AS AD_Data FROM AidatDurum
UNION SELECT UYEID, "Subat", Subat*-1 FROM AidatDurum
UNION SELECT UYEID, "Mart", Mart*-1 FROM AidatDurum
UNION SELECT UYEID, "Nisan", Nisan*-1 FROM AidatDurum;
```

Query:

```
SELECT AA_UNION.UYEID, Sum(AA_Data * AD_Data) AS ToplamBorc
FROM AD_UNION INNER JOIN AA_UNION ON (AD_UNION.AD_Col = AA_UNION.AA_Col) AND (AD_UNION.UYEID = AA_UNION.UYEID)
GROUP BY AA_UNION.UYEID;
```